# WinUI3: The thread cannot manipulate the control after switching pages

Tags: c#, winui-3

I discovered this issue while running my project. And for now, I'm going to simplify it and reproduce the whole issue.

Now we have two pages: `MainPage` and `BlankPage`
In **MainPage.xaml**, there is a textbox

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestAPP.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="400" Width="900"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In **MainPage.xaml.cs**, I'll have the textbox show the current time every 500 milliseconds

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using static TestAPP.App;

namespace TestAPP.Views;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void example_function()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
            {
                textBox.Text += DateTime.Now + "  ";
            });
        }    
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(example_function);
        if (GlobalVariables.flag)
        {
            t.Start();
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread start!");
            GlobalVariables.flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid threads starting every time when navigate to `MainPage`, I introduced `GlobalVariables.flag`， so in `App.xaml.cs` I defined it

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static bool flag = true;
}
```

---

I expected the textbox to keep showing current time, but actually, when I navigated to `BlankPage` and then switched back to `MainPage`, the thread didn't work properly: The textbox stopped constantly displaying the current time.
As shown by the GIF below
[image: GIF]

Comment: `GlobalVariables.flag` is initially `true`, then you set it to `false` when navigating to the page, after you have started the Thread (not clear why you're not using a Timer instead). When you get back, to a new instance of that page, the Thread doesn't start, because `GlobalVariables.flag` is `false`

Comment: Besides that you should use a [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-22621) here, you should generally not be using threads explicitly at all. Use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios) with [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0).

Comment: When navigating back to **MainPage**, the previous thread has already started, and set `GlobalVariables.flag` `false` is to avoid starting the thread repeatedly

Comment: When you navigate back, it is not the same MainPage instance, and hence also not the same TextBox instance that the thread would update. Throw your code away and start over with a timer.

Comment: In this example it works, but in my project the role of the thread is to update the contents of the TextBox when data is received from 127.0.0.1:5701, so I can't use the `DispatcherTimer `

Comment: Maybe you can't use DispatcherTimer but the code here doesn't work, and it has nothing to do with WinUI3

Comment: So what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Rewrite something that truly exhibit what you want to achieve, your current code is buggy anyway (WinUI3 or not) as explained by jimi

Comment: Maybe my expression is misleading, but what I wrote is simplified code for the problem I encountered. I hope the `textbox` to keep showing current time even after swiching back  to *MainPage*, and `DispatchTimer` does not fit my project

Comment: Your problem is a problem in your code, not in WinUI3. Jimi explained all that already

Comment: [Frame.Navigate Method Causes the Frame to load content represented by the specified Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3). As @Jimi said, the Frame loads a new page instance every time. Try letting the `textBox` global and update it when Frame.Navigated or Page.OnNavigatedTo. Andrew KeepCoding's answer also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you an example using the `PeriodicTimer`:

```cs
public sealed partial class PageA : Page
{
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;

    public PageA()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        try
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource = new();

            using PeriodicTimer periodicTimer = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            while (await periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token) is true)
            {
                TimeTextBox.Text += DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
    }
}
```